# Problem with a vectorized operation with 2 logical vectors: replace values in first vector to NA according to FALSE values in the other vector

Tags: r, vector, boolean, vectorization

I have a question about a vectorized operation with logical vectors. In my problem, there are two vectors: main and secondary. They're both of the same length. I want to replace some elements in the *main* vector to `NA`, based on insights I gather from the *secondary* vector.

- The main vector is comprised of `TRUE` and `FALSE` that can appear in any random order.
- The secondary vector is either:

  - a sequence of `TRUE` then a sequence of `FALSE` with/without `NA` as the last element; *or*
  - all `TRUE`; *or*
  - all `FALSE`; *or*
  - all `FALSE` with last element as `NA`; *or*
  - all `TRUE` with last element as `NA`

I'll provide several examples below and explain the desired algorithm.

**A - The most common case**

replace `x` values with `NA` for positions that are `FALSE` in `y`

```r
# here, `x` is the main vector
x <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NA)

# `y` is the secondary vector
y <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)

# `z` is the desired output
z <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA, NA) # in this case only index 7 in `x` actually changed
```

**B - The secondary vector is all `FALSE`**

```r
x2 <- c(FALSE, NA)
y2 <- c(FALSE, FALSE)

# desired output
z2 <- c(NA, NA)
```

**C - The secondary vector is all `TRUE`**

```r
x3 <- rep(FALSE, 4)
y3 <- rep(TRUE, 4)

# desired output
z3 <- rep(FALSE, 4)
```

---

**My attempt**

I've almost figured this out, but unfortunately it fails with scenario **B**.

```r
my_func <- function(main, secondary) {
  
  idx_last_true_in_secondary <- max(which(secondary))
  
  if(idx_last_true_in_secondary == length(secondary)) {
    return(main)
  }
  
  main[(idx_last_true_in_secondary + 1): length(main)] <- NA
  main
}

# case A
my_func(x, y)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA

# case B
my_func(x2, y2)
#> Warning in max(which(secondary)): no non-missing arguments to max; returning
#> -Inf
#> Error in (idx_last_true_in_secondary + 1):length(main): result would be too long a vector

# case C
my_func(x3, y3)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

My question is whether anyone sees a better way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work as expected:

```
my_func <- function(main,secondary ) {
  main[!secondary] <- NA
  return(main)
}

my_func(x,y)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA

my_func(x2,y2)
[1] NA NA

my_func(x3,y3)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

We could do it this way:

```
my_func <- function(x, y) {
  replace(x, !y, NA)
}
```

How it works:

```
# A
replace(x, !y, NA)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA

# B
replace(x2, !y2, NA)
[1] NA NA

# C
replace(x3, !y3, NA)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

my_func(x,y)
my_func(x2,y2)
my_func(x3,y3)
```

output:

```
> my_func(x,y)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA
> my_func(x2,y2)
[1] NA NA
> my_func(x3,y3)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try `ifelse` like below

```
> ifelse(y,x,NA) 
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA    NA
```